# How can I understand how much my query will make use of tempdb.mdf?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

How can I understand if my T-SQL script will use tempdb.mdf by looking how the SELECT query is structured?

Comment: Clearly if it's using a temp table. Or if you set snapshot isolation level. And inspect the query plan, joins and sorting may use tempdb. It's used for lots of things really.

Answer (score 0):

As @TomT stated in the first comment TempDB is used in a lot of things. Temporary tables lies in the tempDB but also many "behind the curtains" operations ill take advantage of that "memory space" to store temporary data for sorting, joining tables, etc.

In fact you can see TempDB as a special "memory" where SQL engine ill put anything is to large or in some aspect don't fit or don't take advantage on the RAM.

In general you don't need to worry about that things. Are you worrying about your TempDB growing?

For a answer: You can look at your actual execution plan, resources (memory, CPU, etc) usage, some "global variables", System SP, statistics and so on.
Due to engine using the TempDB by demand there's no mean to say ahead, with precision at least,how much it ill be used without a loot of tests.